# How to read csv inside a folder in R?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

I am working in a directory, but the data I want to read is in a subdirectory. I get an error when I try to read the csv files, my code is the following:

```
setwd("~/Documents/")
files <- list.files(path = "data/")
f <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  f[[i]] <- read.csv(files[i], header = T, sep = ";")
}
```

And the error I get is:

`Error in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `paste0("data/", files[i])`. `files` contains file names, not relative paths.

Comment: using `list.files(path = "data/", full.names = TRUE)` will likely solve the problem.

Comment: thanks @user2706569 work perfectly.

Comment: thanks @Benjamin you're answer also works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work, assuming you have correctly specified the other read.csv parameters.

```
setwd("~/Documents/")
files <- list.files(path = "data/")
f <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  f[[i]] <- read.csv(paste0("data/",files[i]), header = T, sep = ";")
}
```

Alternatively, you could drop the `paste0` and simply set your working directory to `~/Documents/data/` in the first place.

```
setwd("~/Documents/data/")
files <- list.files() #No parameter necessary now since you're in the proper directory
f <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  f[[i]] <- read.csv(files[i], header = T, sep = ";")
}
```

If you need to be in `~/Documents/` at the end of this loop, then finish it up by adding the following after the loop.

```
setwd("~/Documents/")
```

Comment: thanks, I need to use a subdirectory because I have more files in the main directory as I'm working in a Rstudio project.